# Connect to right custom Exchange server

Tags: c++, authentication, wsdl, exchangewebservices, gsoap

I am trying to implement a client side service which exchange data with exchange server, so i'm using gSoap library. 
However i want that any user can access their own mail data with their official mail credentials via my this client service.

I'm using wsdl file from https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/services.wsdl to get methods info from exchange server.

**Q1.** Does this wsdl file work for every exchange server, since my plan is that first i'm trying to authenticate user and then i'll use this wsdl for process operation on exchange server with ews. so is this right approach? if this is not then what would be your advice for this?

**Q2.** For gSoap can i use autodiscover and i found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332364.aspx link for autodiscover, does can i use with gSoap? if yes then how(any help).

Believe me i have searched it on google many times but could not find specific answer.

Please help me, Thank you.

Comment: This http://blog.skysoft-is.com/?p=78 says that "outlook.office365.com – which is global alias and does not pointing to actual server" So if use this as endpoint location, is this help me to redirect me to actual server? am i right? thank you.

Comment: please tell me what the wrong with my question if you think please. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that for custom exchange server location(end point) i have to manually change the `soap_endpoint = "https://example.com/service.aspx"` or if not, then i can set it to NULL for take the end-point location from WSDL file.